# Cannot insert multiple objects without calling SaveChanges() every time

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to add several objects to the DB with EF ObjectContext without calling the `SaveChanges()` after each add. Problem is that only the last added object is committed to the DB.

```
using (var entities = new ModelEntities())
{
    foreach (service in services)
    {
       entities.Services.AddObject(service);
    }
    entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I call the `SaveChanges()` method directly after `AddObject` all objects are inserted but performance is affected. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
using (var entities = new ModelEntities())
{
    foreach (var s in services)
    {
       var service = s;
       entities.Services.AddObject(service);
    }
    entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I don't see why this would produce any different performance results, it looks the same to me. can you explain what this will do and why it affects performance?

Comment: It's not about performance. The original code wasn't working because EF only added the last object referenced by `service` when the loop had finished. Here, `service` is scoped within the loop so every object is added. (Perhaps someone can do a better job of explaining!)